# Change language on Get Satisfaction?

Tags: localization, getsatisfaction.com

Is there any way to change the language of page / widget on Get Satisfaction?

It's set to English by default, but we'd like to change it to German.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GetSatisfaction only supports English right now. At least according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Get_Satisfaction).

Comment: Unfortunately that's what I thought. Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 0):

GetSatisfaction is now available in a range of languages, but only on [paid plans](https://getsatisfaction.com/corp/pricing/). From the [help page](https://getsatisfaction.com/corp/help/multiple-language-support/):

> In addition to English, Get Satisfaction communities are available in
>   the following languages: Spanish, French, German, Italian, Portuguese,
>   Dutch, Swedish, Norwegian, Danish, and Finnish. Multiple language
>   support is available for communities on the Connect plan, and higher,
>   and can easily be configured from the Admin section.